# Elasticsearch Find Out does user stops or moving - Possible?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-painless, elasticsearch-mapping

I want to use elasticsearch configuration about mapping to display user location and his/her direction to admin in my web app. so I create an index in elasticsearch like:

```
{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "number_of_shards": 5,
      "number_of_replicas": 1
    },
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "analyzer-name": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "keyword",
          "filter": "lowercase"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
        "properties": {
          "driver_id": { "type": "integer" },
          "email": { "type": "text" },
          "location": { "type": "geo_point" },
          "app-platform": { "type": "text" },
          "app-version": { "type": "text" },
          "created_at": { "type": "date", "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss||yyyy-MM-dd||epoch_millis"}
        }
    }
}
```

and start to inserting user location to elasticsearch with this curl

```
{
    "driver_id": 357,
    "driver_email": "Andrew@mailinatior.com",
    "location": {
        "lat": 37.3,
        "lon": 59.52
    },
    "created_at": "2021-06-04 00:09:00"
}
```

this structure came from user mobile to my elasticsearch, after that I wrote these services to fetch data for my web-end part of my designing:

```
module Api
  module V1
    module Drivers
      module Elastic
        class LiveLocation
          include Peafowl

          attribute :driver_id, ::Integer

          def call
            @driver = ::Driver.find(driver_id) if driver_id.present?
            result = []
            options = {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
                },
                body: @driver.present? ? options_with_driver : options
            }
            begin
              response = HTTParty.get(elasticseach_url.to_s, options)
              records = JSON.parse(response.body)['hits']['hits']
              if records.present?
                records.group_by { |r| r['_source']['driver_id'] }.to_a.each do |record|
                  driver = ::Driver.where(id: record[0]).first
                  if driver.present?
                    location = record[1][0]['_source']['location']
                    app_platform = record[1][0]['_source']['app-platform']
                    app_version = record[1][0]['_source']['app-version']
                    result.push(driver_id: driver.id, driver_email: driver.profile.email, location: location, app_platform: app_platform, app_version: app_version)
                  end
                end
              end
            rescue StandardError => error
              Rails.logger.info "Error => #{error}"
              result = []
            end
            context[:response] = result
          end

          def elasticseach_url
            "#{ENV.fetch('ELASTICSEARCH_BASE_URL', 'http://127.0.0.1:9200')}/#{ENV.fetch('ELASTICSEARCH_DRIVER_POSITION_INDEX', 'live_location')}/_search"
          end

          def options
            {
                query: {
                    bool: {
                        filter: [
                            {
                                range: {
                                    created_at: {
                                        gte: (Time.now.beginning_of_day.strftime '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                sort: [
                    {
                        created_at: {
                            order: 'desc'
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }.to_json
          end

          def optinos_with_driver
            {
                query: {
                    bool: {
                        must: [
                            {
                                term: {
                                    driver_id: {
                                        value: @driver.id
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        filter: [
                            {
                                range: {
                                    created_at: {
                                        gte: (Time.now.beginning_of_day.strftime '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                sort: [
                    {
                        created_at: {
                            order: 'desc'
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }.to_json
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

this structure working perfectly but even if the user stops while elasticsearch saves his location but I need to filter user data that if the user stops for one hour in place elasticsearch understand and not saving data. Is it possible?
I use elsticsearch 7.1
and ruby 2.5

I know it's possible in kibana but I could not using kibana at this tim.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this can be done via a single ES query...

**However you can use 2 queries:**

- one to check if the user's location's during the last hour is the same
- Second same then don't insert
- But i don't recommend that

**What you could do:**

- Use REDIS or any in-mem cache to maintain the user's last geo-location duration
- Basis that, update or skip update to Elastic Search

**PS:** I am not familiar with ES geo-location API